# Example of second preimage attack

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis, 2nd-preimage-resistance

Please, I'm trying to understand second-preimage attacks on cryptographic hash functions. I understand the definition well: given a message and it's hash, an attacker finds another message which results in the same hash value. What I need is an explanation of a successful attack on a real hash function.

I have read lots of articles (from journals - especially Lecture Notes in Computer Science) on successful second-preimage attacks on some cryptographic hash functions but my mind can't get to grasp it properly.

What I need is a practical example (with explanation please) of a second preimage on MD4 using the attack developed by Wang et al in their paper "[The Second Preimage Attack on MD4](http://www.infosec.sdu.edu.cn/uploadfile/papers/The%20Second-Preimage%20Attack%20on%20MD4.pdf)" ([alternate link](https://web.archive.org/web/20110813121836/http://www.infosec.sdu.edu.cn/uploadfile/papers/The%20Second-Preimage%20Attack%20on%20MD4.pdf))

Edit(1): Or, better still, can I have an explained example of a second preimage attack using the attack presented by F. Mendel et al. in the paper [A (Second) Preimage Attack on the GOST Hash Function](http://bib.tiera.ru/b/74682#page=233) 
I'm desperately in need of some kind of simple step-by-step practical example of a successful attack.

Edit(2): Going back to the second preimage attack on MD4 based on the paper above, a working example is given (Table 2 on page 9 in the paper). I can leave out trying to understand the transformation from the target message **M_0** to the weak message **M**, what I really need is some kind of step-by-step explanation of how the second-preimage **M'** was discovered using the method given. 
Please, I am new to cryptography, so an explanation of this example (or any other for that matter) is what can enable me understand this faster and better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you ask a specific question about any particular preimage attack, I would love to answer. Explaining an attack from scratch would take the same amount of text as the original paper.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Crypto.SE. As Dmitry points out your question need a huge amount of text to be properly answered. This is why I'm voting to close as `too broad` at this point. Of course you can edit it to limit the scope and make it more "answerable"; I'll leave it up to you. In the meantime try browsing some other questions with the same tag, and maybe you'll find something useful. I hope this helps.

Comment: I've edited my question by narrowing down the request: all I ask for now is a short (practical) example of a second preimage attack on MD4. Hope this is more "answerable" and less broad. Thank you.

Comment: The paper is a second-preimage attack with a restriction: it works for a fraction ($1/2^{56}$) of messages. If your are content with similar restriction to $1/2^{511}$ of messages, you can just use the example in table 2: for any $X$, a second-preimage of $M||X$ (resp. $M'||X$) is $M'||X$ (resp. $M||X$). For the full attack, you choose you own first block $\widehat{M_0}$, follow what the paper prescribes to get $\widehat M$ and $\widehat{M'}$, then proceed as I explained before. Tell us what part of _what the paper prescribes_ you have issue with, that might help re-open the question.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help fgrieu. Your comment was really very helpful, I did not get the weak message part, but after re-reading I think have now got it.
The thing is I'm a "newbie" in cryptography and that is why I needed some kind of concrete example of a successful attack to help me better understand second preimages.
This is the reason why I've shifted from the MD4 I asked previously to GOST, hoping with this my question is easier to answer.

Comment: The new GOST paper claims a " _complexity of about_ $2^{225}$ _evaluations of the compression function_ "; I suggest you ponder what that number means in term of time for the hardware you have. The MD4 paper allows a concrete implementation of a program that accepts any file matching some simple constraint on how it starts, and quickly spits a different file with the same MD4 hash, as verifiable with a reference MD4 implementation. With the first implementation strategy that I suggested, the program is dead simple. A file editor like HxD can even be used to perform the attack without coding.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot then @fgrieu. I will follow your advice and edit my question (again) to try to stick to the attack on MD4 (I'm having serious issues with the whole "weak message" idea).

Comment: A very general sketch of the attack: we want a second preimage of some message starting in $M$ (of sixteen 32-bit words). By using the procedure in the paper's 4.3 (with reference to other parts), we check if $M$ is weak for some $i$. If yes, which has odds $2^{-56}$, all there is to do to find the second preimage is toggle the $i+1$-th bit in the fifth word of our original message. Section 4.4 explain how to find a message such that this procedure works, with $M$ Hamming-close to any prescribed $M_0$ we want. In the paper $M_0$ was chosen with all bits set, that seems arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks @fgrieu. Actually, I think **M0** was chosen as an arbitrary example to be used to explain the transformation to the _weak_ _message_ **M** from which the second-preimage **M'** was found. Now, my difficulty here, is understanding exactly HOW **M'** was obtained from **M** using the method given. I haven't been able to follow the method provided in the paper (i.e. to find the second-preimage **M'**)

Comment: What's wrong with "_toggle the $i+1$-th bit in the fifth word_" in my comment, or $m_4\gets m_4\oplus\text{0x400000}$ in the paper's 4.4, which is how $M'$ is obtained from $M$?

Comment: OK, well, @fgrieu thanks a lot for your help. I guess the problem is that my math is probably not up to level to grasp this without further explanations. I will try to read it again and see if your comments make any more sense...

Comment: Please do. I think you'll find that the real hard part is  _not_ how $M'$ is derived from $M$, but how $M$ is derived from $M_0$ in such a way that $M'$ can be derived from $M$; the later requires the preliminaries in 4.1 and 4.2 in the paper, with reference to section 3; and uh, even 5 comments are not enough to touch that.